# How to change the label from back button in Ionic 2?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic2

With the code:

```
<ion-navbar *navbar>
</ion-navbar>
```

the back button is enabled. But I need to customize it (the icon or the label). Is it possible?
Can't find anything in the docs/api.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

you can set back button text in your app.html as mentioned in the ionic link http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/config/Config

```
@App({
  template: `<ion-nav [root]="root"></ion-nav>`
  config: {
    backButtonText: 'Go Back',
    iconMode: 'ios',
    modalEnter: 'modal-slide-in',
    modalLeave: 'modal-slide-out',
    tabbarPlacement: 'bottom',
    pageTransition: 'ios',
  }
})
```

**UPDATE in ionic 2 beta 8**

```
import {ionicBootstrap} from 'ionic-angular';

ionicBootstrap(AppRoot, customProviders, {
  backButtonText: 'Go Back',
  iconMode: 'ios',
  modalEnter: 'modal-slide-in',
  modalLeave: 'modal-slide-out',
  tabbarPlacement: 'bottom',
  pageTransition: 'ios',
});
```

**UPDATE in ionic 2 rc.0 and up, as well as ionic 3**

In ionic 2 rc.0 and up, we need to include the configs in **app.module.ts** under imports array.

```
@NgModule({   
 declarations: [
    MyApp,
    Home   
 ],   
 imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
      tabsPlacement: 'top',
      backButtonText: 'Back'
     })],
 bootstrap: [IonicApp],
 entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    Home   ],
 providers: [MyService]
})
```

Comment: Hi. Is it possible to change the icon and text on the back button for one specific page?

Comment: I have not tried it. Just look at setBackButtonText() in http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/nav/ViewController/#setBackButtonText. Hope it helps

Answer (score 28):

The current version of IONIC2 allows you to change the text of the back-button globally.

You can also change the icon like it appears in ios and hide the `"Back"` label.

```
imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp,{
      backButtonText: '',
      backButtonIcon: 'ios-arrow-back',
      iconMode: 'md'
    })
]
```

Just add this one to your `app.module.ts`.

Comment: in current version "3.12.1" this is the answer

Answer (score 11):

I've just spent a while working out how to do this via the [ViewController](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/navigation/ViewController/#setBackButtonText) in Ionic 2.

Inside the typescript file for your page you must import the ViewController

`import { ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';`

Then in your constructor function include the ViewController.

`constructor(public viewCtrl: ViewController) {}`

Then finally you can call the function to change the text.

`ionViewDidLoad() {
   this.viewCtrl.setBackButtonText('Cancel');
}`

I basically cobbled this together from how I'd been doing Alerts and Nav Controller stuff so I may be wrong. It's working for me though and has the benefit of allowing me to change the text on a per page basis.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using ionic 4 you can set back button text like this

```
<ion-back-button [text]="'<your text>'"></ion-back-button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here official documentation https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/config/Config/

there is a good example of usage in the ionic 3 starter app

In costructor of app.component.ts is used "set" method used of Config object from ionic-angular:

```
this.config.set('ios', 'backButtonText', values.BACK_BUTTON_TEXT);
```

Is usefull when you want to use internationalization or if you want change configs dynamically:

```
this.translate.get(['BACK_BUTTON_TEXT']).subscribe(values => {
  this.config.set('ios', 'backButtonText', values.BACK_BUTTON_TEXT);
```