# Change ionic back button text like in IOS

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular5

I wanted to change the ionic back button text with previous page view name like in iPhone. If it navigates from `Users` to `User detail` I wanted the back text to be changed to `Users` in user detail page view.

For now this is what I got from browsing for a solution.

```
imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
      tabsPlacement: 'top',
      backButtonText: 'Back',
      iconMode: 'ios',
      modalEnter: 'modal-slide-in',
      modalLeave: 'modal-slide-out',
      tabbarPlacement: 'bottom',
      pageTransition: 'ios'
     })
  ]
```

This will change the default. How can I change `backButtonText` value with page name from stack programmatically.

Answer (score 2):

To dynamically change the back button text, you can use the `ViewContoller.setBackButtonText()` method.
See: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/ViewController/

To get the previous page title, you should probably look for what the `NavController.last()` can give you.

Inject the ViewController into your component.

```
import { ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';
constructor(private viewController: ViewController) {}
```

Then you need to set the text in one the component lifecycle event that happen after the DOM is loaded:

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.viewController.setBackButtonText('My Back Button Text');
}
```

See Ionic "Lifecycle events" doc to find which one fits your need. https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/

I give all the code credit (and thanks) to the gentleman of the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42013787/1321664